How many ways can you make change?
The "third type of Euler Transform" takes an integer sequence that gives the number of objects of a given weight and outputs a sequences that gives the number of multisets of objects that sum to that weight.
In this code-golf challenge, you will be performing an analogous transform on lists.
Example
For example, let's say our (\$1\$-indexed) sequence is (2,1,0,0,2).
We might interpret this as saying that we have

2 types of 1¢ coins (say copper and steel, denoted "c" and "s")
1 type of 2¢ coins (denoted "2")
0 types of 3¢ coins
0 types of 4¢ coins
2 types of 5¢ coins (say Buffalo and Jefferson, denoted "B" and "J")

Now the Euler transform tells us how many distinct ways we can make change. This (1-indexed) sequence starts

1¢:  2 (c/s)
2¢:  4 (cc/cs/ss/2)
3¢:  6 (ccc/ccs/css/sss/c2/s2)
4¢:  9 (cccc/cccs/ccss/csss/ssss/cc2/cs2/ss2/22)
5¢: 14 (ccccc/ccccs/cccss/ccsss/cssss/sssss/ccc2/ccs2/css2/sss2/c22/s22/B/J)
[it continues 20, 28, 37, 48, 63, 80, 101, 124, ...]

The challenge
You will take an input which is a collection of objects and their weights in any reasonable format. For example, you might input a list of lists of strings, for example:
input = [
  [],         # index 0
  ["c", "s"], # index 1
  ["2"],      # index 2
  [],         # index 3
  [],         # index 4
  ["B","J"]   # index 5
]

You will then write a function which takes this collection of objects along with a positive integer n. Your function should return all of the multisets whose weight sums to \$n\$ that are composed of the objects in the input.
For example, if you use the input given above, and \$n=3\$, then f(input, 3) should return something like
[
  ["c","c","c"],
  ["c","c","s"],
  ["c","s","s"],
  ["s","s","s"],
  ["c","2"],
  ["s","2"]
]

Just like the input, the output can be in any reasonable format.
This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.

is there a maximum number of types one coin can come in? otherwise representing it will be incredibly difficult. If not, can we just use a list [[0,1], 2, 1]  for one 1 cent, two 2 cent and one 3 cent

In the spirit of outputting a sequence, could I/O be relaxed to standard [tag:sequence] I/O (i.e. also permitting first-n or infinite output)?

@pacman256—I'm having trouble parsing your proposed input, but in general any (human-readable) input that captures the underlying structure is fine.

@UnrelatedString—yep, this is fine!

It's a nested list where each item represents a different type of the same value

Can we assume that the list at index #0 is either absent or always empty?

@Arnauld—yep, there are zero objects of weight zero (otherwise there'd be an infinite number of possibilities!)

Jelly, 15 14 bytes
ŒṗịŒp€ẎṢ€Qɓ;Ṭ}

Try it online!
Oh yeah...
Given n on the left and the objects (with no 0 list!) on the right, outputs the nth collection of multisets.
Œṗ                Integer partitions of n.
  ị               Index each integer in each partition into
          ɓ       the objects
           ;      concatenated with
            Ṭ}    n-1 0s and a 1,
   Œp€            take the Cartesian product of the lists in each partition,
      Ẏ           flatten the partitions out,
       Ṣ€         sort each combination,
         Q        and uniquify.

Jelly, 31 26 23 bytes
Żp"ṚẎẎ€Ṣ€Q
Lr‘ṁƒḷṭ@ÇƤ$/

Try it online!
Given the objects on the left and n on the right, outputs a list of the first n collections of multisets.
Still feels pretty messy.
Lr‘ṁƒḷṭ@ÇƤ$/    Main link: compute the output
   ṁƒḷ          Reshape the list of object lists to each in succession of
Lr              the range from its length to n
  ‘             plus 1.
Lr‘ṁƒḷ          This reuses the empty first list repeatedly to pad to n+1.
           /    Reduce the padded list by
        Ç       calling the helper on
         Ƥ      every prefix of
      ṭ@  $     the accumulator with the current element appended.

Żp"ṚẎẎ€Ṣ€Q    Helper link: paired combinations adding up to length of prefix
Ż             Prepend 0 (rangifies to an empty list) to the prefix,
 p"           and take Cartesian products with corresponding elements of
   Ṛ          the prefix reversed.
    Ẏ         Concatenate the products of each pair,
     Ẏ€       concatenate the pairs in each product,
       Ṣ€     sort each combination,
         Q    and uniquify.

As an amusing aside... I meant to use ¥ in place of $, but there's no difference here, because apparently / coercing its operand to a dyad even affects how said operand chains.

Yeah, IIRC, / never actually checks the arity of the link it's passed. The source code just forces it to be dyadic: return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: dyadic_link(link, (x, y)), array, *init). And, because this passes it to dyadic_link, it chains as a dyadic link, even if not parsed that way

@cairdcoinheringaahing That's the unsurprising part--what caught me off guard is that adicity isn't intrinsic to grouping (or line-reference!) quicks for the purposes of their own internal chaining. I believe it's actually line 906 that's the culprit from my point of view. Intuitively, I would have expected $/ to be equivalent to ${/ rather than ¥--guess I need to revise that tip!

Charcoal, 52 bytes
⊞υ⊞ＯＥθκωＦυ≡§Ｉ⁻↨Ｅ§ι±¹§θκ¹η⁰0…⮌ι¹-¿⊖Ｌι⊞⊞ＯυΦιλ⊞Ｏι⁺⊟ι§ι⁰

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the collection as a dictionary mapping coin identifiers to values. Explanation:
⊞υ⊞ＯＥθκωＦυ

Start a breadth-first search with all coin identifiers and no coins chosen so far.
≡§Ｉ⁻↨Ｅ§ι±¹§θκ¹η⁰

Compare the value of the coins so far with the desired target.
0…⮌ι¹

If the target has been hit then output the coins.
-¿⊖Ｌι⊞⊞ＯυΦιλ⊞Ｏι⁺⊟ι§ι⁰

If the coins are insufficient then try both skipping the current coin and adding the current coin to the set of coins chosen.

JavaScript (V8), 80 bytes
Expects (list_of_lists)(n) without any list for weight 0. Outputs by printing comma-separated strings.
a=>g=(n,...o)=>n?a.map(b=>n-->0&&b.map(c=>g(n,...o,c))):o+""==o.sort()&&print(o)

Try it online!
Commented
a =>                // outer function taking the input list a[]
g = (               // g = inner recursive function taking:
  n,                //   n   = target sum
  ...o              //   o[] = output
) =>                //
n ?                 // if n is not zero:
  a.map(b =>        //   for each sub-list b[] in a[]:
    n-- > 0         //     abort if n is 0 or less
    &&              //     (decrement n afterwards)
    b.map(c =>      //     otherwise, for each character c in b[]:
      g(n, ...o, c) //       do a recursive call with c added to o[]
    )               //     end of map()
  )                 //   end of map()
:                   // else:
  o + "" ==         //   uniquify by testing if o[] is ...
  o.sort() &&       //   ... lexicographically sorted
  print(o)          //   if it is, print it (e.g. "c,c,s" is printed
                    //   but "c,s,c" and "s,c,c" are not)


05AB1E, 18 bytes
FĆ}¹Åœèε.«âεS{]€`Ù

Inputs in the order \$n,objectLists\$, including an empty list at index 0.
Assumes the objects are always single characters (otherwise the S should be ¸˜ for +1 byte).
Try it online or verify multiple \$n\$ at once.
Explanation:
F }      # Loop the first (implicit) input amount of times:
 Ć       #  Enclose the second (implicit) input-list;
         #  appending its own head (the [] at index 0)
   ¹     # Push the first input-integer n again
    Åœ   # Get all lists of positive integers that sum to this n
      è  # (0-based) index each into the list of lists
ε        # Map over each list of lists:
 .«      #  Reduce each list of lists by:
   â     #   Cartesian product
    ε    #  Map over each reduced list of lists:
     S   #   Convert it to a flattened list of characters
      {  #   Sort this list of characters
]        # Close the nested maps
 €`      # Flatten it one level down
         # (which has as side-effect that each inner list is reversed)
   Ù     # Uniquify this list of lists
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Nekomata, 6 bytes
Ṗ@ᵐ~oũ

Attempt This Online!
A port of @Unrelated String's Jelly answer, but much shorter thanks to Nekomata's non-determinism.
Ṗ@ᵐ~oũ
            Take 2, [[],["a","b"],["c"]] as an example
Ṗ       Find an integer partition of the first input
            Possible results: [1,1] [2]
 @      Index into the second input
            Possible results: [["a","b"],["a","b"]] [["c"]]
  ᵐ     Map:
   ~      Choose any element
            Possible results: ["a","a"] ["a","b"] ["b","a"] ["b","b"] ["c"]
    o   Sort
            Possible results: ["a","a"] ["a","b"] ["a","b"] ["b","b"] ["c"]
     ũ  Uniquify among all possible solutions
            Possible results: ["a","a"] ["a","b"] ["b","b"] ["c"]


Python 3, 103 bytes
def f(c,n):
 if n==0:yield''
 if c and n>0:
  for x in f(c,n-c[1]):yield c[0]+x
  yield from f(c[2:],n)

Try it online!
Expects input in the form
c=[type1,value1,type2,value2,...], and concatenates types for the output.

Python3, 240 bytes
from itertools import*
R=range
def f(c,n):
 q=[([(i+1,c[i])for i in R(len(c))if c[i]],0,[])]
 for c,t,S in q:
  if t==n:yield tuple(sorted(S))
  if c:(i,C),*c=c;q+=[(c,V,[*S,*K])for j in R((n-t)//i+1)for K in product(*[C]*j)if(V:=t+j*i)<=n]

Try it online!

236 bytes

@Lucenaposition Or yield*sorted(S),?

JavaScript (V8), 72 bytes
a=>g=(n,...o)=>n?a.map(b=>n-->0&&b.map(c=>c<o[0]||g(n,c,...o))):print(o)

Try it online!
From Arnauld's

Python 3, 116 bytes
The input doesn't contain the empty index 0 array.
def f(c, n):
 a=set([()]*-~-n)
 for O in c[:n]:n-=1;a|=set(tuple(sorted([*x,o]))for o in O for x in f(c,n))
 return a

Try it online!
If we are allowed to return a garbage character in each of the multisets (i.e. {'$2', '$cs', '$ss', '$cc'} instead of {'2', 'cs', 'ss', 'cc'}, the code below is 114 bytes.
def g(c, n):
 a=set('$'*-~-n)
 for O in c[:n]:n-=1;a|=set(''.join(sorted(x+o))for o in O for x in g(c,n))
 return a

Try it online!

106
